# How to call a service from a controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sendgrid

I am trying to call the following service from a controller:

```
@Service
class MyMailService {

    private final SendGrid sendGrid;

    @Inject
    public SendGridMailService(SendGrid sendGrid) {
        this.sendGrid = sendGrid;
    }

    void sendMail() {
        Request request = new Request();
        Response response = this.sendGrid.api(request);                
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
# controller
public String index(Model model) {
    MyMailService.sendMail() // how to do this properly?
    return "register";
}
```

What would be the correct way to call this from a controller? Basically, I'm trying to "autoconfigure" sendgrid, so I don't have to initialize the SendGrid object with the API key whenever I call the MyMailService class.

Comment: sendMail() is an instance method, not a static method. So you need an instance of MyMailService to call it, that you can inject in your controller. This is fundamental, basic OO stuff. I suggest you spend more time learning the basics (what is a method, what is a static method, what is an object) before diving into more complex stuff.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by others, I do think too you need to spend more time learning Java & Spring basics. But to answer your question, you auto-wire/inject your `service` singleton object in the controller to use it:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerA
{
  .
  .
  .
  @Autowired
  private MyMailService mymailService; //singleton object instance injected to be used/shared by all controllers

public String index(Model model) {
    mymailService.sendMail()
    return "register";
}
  .
  .
  .

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call your service in below ways

1) Simply adding @Autowired to your class type

```
@Autowired
MyMailService myMailService;
```

2) Using Constructor Injection as below,

```
MyMailService myMailService;    

@Autowired
public WebController(MyMailService myMailService) {
    this.myMailService = myMailService;
}


-  here i assumed my Controller name is WebController
```

3) Using Setter Injection as below,

```
MyMailService myMailService;

@Autowired
public void setMyMailService(MyMailService myMailService) {
    this.myMailService = myMailService;
}
```

and finally in your controller you can call your service class methods as below,

```
myMailService.sendMail();
```

Note:
Follow naming convention.